# How to add any custom condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarn-v2

I have created the pricing plans in react using the mapping i have created a array like data.js in the array there are three objects that are the three plans in the first plan i have provided the 4 li items with icon but in the second plan i want 5 li items and in the third plan i want 6 li items but the icon is showing every time even the li is empty i want to do display none of the icon when li is empty how to add the condition please help me out i will attach the screen shot what problem i am facing

[Here is the image of my work i don't want the icons with empty li please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYZQ8.png)

I want to create a custom condition to hide the icons i am sure that i can get my answer from this platform

Comment: Why you are rendering empty li? you must filter that out in logic. include your code in question so somebody can suggest solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.